# Cannot access package manager

Tags: weka, package-managers

I have weka 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9 installed on my Windows 10 computer. I cannot access the package manager in 3.8 or 3.9.

Here is the error message I get when I try (clicking the Tools menu and selecting Package Manager).

```
weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.createSingleton(GUIChooserApp.java:259)
weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.main(GUIChooserApp.java:1805)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
weka.gui.SplashWindow.invokeMain(SplashWindow.java:306)
weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:92)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.loadInstalledPackageCache(DefaultPackageManager.java:1284)
at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(DefaultPackageManager.java:1178)
at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackage.getMissingDependencies(DefaultPackage.java:460)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.loadCheck(WekaPackageManager.java:785)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.loadPackages(WekaPackageManager.java:1156)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.loadPackages(WekaPackageManager.java:1107)
at weka.gui.GenericObjectEditor.determineClasses(GenericObjectEditor.java:187)
at weka.gui.GenericObjectEditor.<clinit>(GenericObjectEditor.java:257)
at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.<init>(GUIChooserApp.java:740)
at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.createSingleton(GUIChooserApp.java:259)
at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp.main(GUIChooserApp.java:1805)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at weka.gui.SplashWindow.invokeMain(SplashWindow.java:306)
at weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:92)
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pentaho.packageManagement.DefaultPackage
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.loadInstalledPackageCache(DefaultPackageManager.java:1284)
weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(DefaultPackageManager.java:1178)
weka.core.WekaPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(WekaPackageManager.java:1829)
weka.gui.PackageManager.getPackagesAndEstablishLookup(PackageManager.java:2365)
weka.gui.PackageManager.getAllPackages(PackageManager.java:2445)
weka.gui.PackageManager.<init>(PackageManager.java:1517)
weka.gui.GUIChooserApp$11$1.run(GUIChooserApp.java:822)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.loadInstalledPackageCache(DefaultPackageManager.java:1284)
at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(DefaultPackageManager.java:1178)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(WekaPackageManager.java:1829)
at weka.gui.PackageManager.getPackagesAndEstablishLookup(PackageManager.java:2365)
at weka.gui.PackageManager.getAllPackages(PackageManager.java:2445)
at weka.gui.PackageManager.<init>(PackageManager.java:1517)
at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp$11$1.run(GUIChooserApp.java:822)
A problem has occurred whilst trying to get all package information. Trying a cache refresh...
Refresh in progress. Please wait...
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 3 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 64 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 67 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 95 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 126 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 133 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 191 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 199 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 254 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 262 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 317 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 324 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 346 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 380 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 390 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 419 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 443 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 446 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 475 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 501 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 505 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 508 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 541 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 568 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 571 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 605 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 627 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 631 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 634 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 684 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 694 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 697 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 729 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 746 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 757 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 760 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 794 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 819 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 822 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 840 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 872 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 882 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 884 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 885 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 895 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 926 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 945 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 946 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 948 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 989 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1008 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1009 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1011 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1016 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1050 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1071 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1074 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1075 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1087 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1098 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1126 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1133 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1138 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1139 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1142 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1156 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1196 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1200 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1202 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1218 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1221 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1253 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1259 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1263 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1265 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1282 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1300 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1319 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1322 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1326 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1327 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1346 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1352 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1379 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1384 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1389 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1390 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1403 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1438 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1443 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1447 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1452 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1453 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1466 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1475 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1504 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1510 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1514 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1516 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1531 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1536 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1545 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1567 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1571 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1573 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1577 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1579 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1593 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1599 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1605 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1622 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1630 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1636 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1637 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1640 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1641 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1656 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1662 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1668 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1685 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1692 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1698 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1703 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1704 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1708 KB
[DefaultPackageManager] downloaded 1708 KB
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pentaho.packageManagement.DefaultPackage
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.loadInstalledPackageCache(DefaultPackageManager.java:1284)
weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(DefaultPackageManager.java:1178)
weka.core.WekaPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(WekaPackageManager.java:1829)
weka.gui.PackageManager.getPackagesAndEstablishLookup(PackageManager.java:2365)
weka.gui.PackageManager.getAllPackages(PackageManager.java:2455)
weka.gui.PackageManager.<init>(PackageManager.java:1517)
weka.gui.GUIChooserApp$11$1.run(GUIChooserApp.java:822)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.loadInstalledPackageCache(DefaultPackageManager.java:1284)
at weka.core.packageManagement.DefaultPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(DefaultPackageManager.java:1178)
at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(WekaPackageManager.java:1829)
at weka.gui.PackageManager.getPackagesAndEstablishLookup(PackageManager.java:2365)
at weka.gui.PackageManager.getAllPackages(PackageManager.java:2455)
at weka.gui.PackageManager.<init>(PackageManager.java:1517)
at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp$11$1.run(GUIChooserApp.java:822)
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NullPointerException
weka.gui.PackageManager.updateTable(PackageManager.java:2246)
weka.gui.PackageManager.<init>(PackageManager.java:2107)
weka.gui.GUIChooserApp$11$1.run(GUIChooserApp.java:822)

at weka.gui.PackageManager.updateTable(PackageManager.java:2246)
at weka.gui.PackageManager.<init>(PackageManager.java:2107)
at weka.gui.GUIChooserApp$11$1.run(GUIChooserApp.java:822)
```

Comment: Try deleting the installedPackageCache.ser file in ~/wekafiles/packages/ and then restart Weka.

Comment: that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I've removed tags from the title and removed the windows tag, as the question does not directly concern windows, but rather weka.

Comment: @Jen ill post it as an answer then

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `installedPackageCache.ser` file in `~/wekafiles/packages/`
and then restart Weka.